# Facebook API ads post not publish

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I have successfully created Ads post using Facebook marketing API but the post did not get publish to the page automatically. I have to manually publish it on powereditor. Can anyone advise me what could be the problem please?

```
$video_data = new AdCreativeVideoData();
$video_data->setData(array(
AdCreativeVideoDataFields::DESCRIPTION => 'try it out',
AdCreativeVideoDataFields::IMAGE_URL => 'IMAGE_URL',
AdCreativeVideoDataFields::VIDEO_ID => 'VIDEO_ID',
AdCreativeLinkDataFields::CALL_TO_ACTION => array(
    'type' => AdCreativeCallToActionTypeValues::NO_BUTTON,
    'value' => array(
    'link' => 'URL',
    'link_caption' => 'Test',
    ),
),
));
$object_story_spec = new AdCreativeObjectStorySpec();
$object_story_spec->setData(array(
  AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::PAGE_ID => 'PAGE_ID',
  AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::VIDEO_DATA => $video_data,
));
$creative = new AdCreative(null, 'act_AD_ACCOUNT_ID');
$creative->setData(array(
  AdCreativeFields::NAME => 'Sample Creative',
  AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_STORY_SPEC => $object_story_spec,
));
$creative->create();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using "inline post creation", where post params are specified inside creative's `object_story_spec`. Since its intended usage is for ads, default behavior is that all created posts are unpublished.

From [FB docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative-object-story-spec/):

> The specifications of a creative containing the page id and other content to create a new **unpublished page post**

---

To create ad for published post, create the post first by posting directly on the page (`POST /<page_id>/feed`) and then use the post ID in creative's `object_story_id`.

Comment: If I post directly on page using POST /<page_id>/feed, will I be able to get CALL_TO_ACTION working? I used to try this and post was successfully created but CALL_TO_ACTION was ignored.

Comment: Your example code shows `<video_id>`, which is something you'll get after uploading the video to page. On that uploading call (`POST /<page_id>/videos`) you can specify `published` parameter to make the video public. Then just follow the example code. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Apologise me! I didn't get what you have mentioned here. My purpose is to post video on Facebook page and the posted video should come with  call_to_action button. I used to get video posted on page using page_id/feed but call_to_action button was completely ignored. After a month of research, I think facebook marketing api can do page post with call_to_action but it is not publish by default. Please advise me sample code to archive this. thanks